# Whether "|" operator could be used for meaning "or"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

I'm trying to write annotation for a function, it has two possible returns, so I writed like this:

```
def func() -> None | True:
    ...
```

then I ran it, but it gave error like this:

> *TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'NoneType' and 'bool'*

I have already used this writing method in Python version 3.10, and it worked perfectly,
but now, in version 3.11.4, seems not working at all.

Then I tried to find solutions on the Internet, one of the most popular answers is to use "typing" module.

So I modified my code, like this:

```
from typing import Union

def func() -> Union[None, True]:
    ...
```

It's really useful, error was gone, but why?

I found the main file of "typing" module and found the type Union on line 654, and I saw its description written as follows:

> ***"On Python 3.10 and higher, the | operator can also be used to denote unions;"***

So my Python version is 3.11.4, but this operator did not work as expected?

I'm really confused about this and hope someone can help me explain. Thank you.

Here some pictures may help.

[Unmodified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdiQd.png)

[Modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsGbm.png)

[Error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yyGi.png)

[Python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBXud.png)

Comment: I cannot replicate your error with the same python version. Please provide the full code /error trace.

Comment: Your machine might have multiple versions of Python installed. Are you sure you are running your snippet using a version >= 3.10?

Comment: I'm quite sure about that, vscode won't deceive me.

Comment: So I will post some pictures, wait a minute.

Comment: Ok the problem comes from `None | True`. It should be `None | bool`

Answer (score 2):

The answer comes from @rochard4u:

> Ok the problem comes from None | True. It should be None | bool